# Is retrieval of sequence nextVal through java is faster than firing a select query on a table?

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to retrieve a sequence value from my Java code.

```
Select sequence.nextVal from dual;
```

Does this query execute faster than a normal select query to any table?
I am confused as sequences have their values cached. So, do they store these values in the RAM, and hence, the faster retrieval?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably faster but it's still going to be done by the database. This has nothing to do with Java. It's going to be faster because it's a very simple operatoin, database can cache results of query's as well.

Comment: Queries can also have their values cached. If you really want to speed things up between Java and Oracle then move the business logic into a stored procedure and then make one call from Java to invoke the stored procedure rather than doing multiple back-and-forths getting sequence values and performing updates of multiple tables in separate requests.

Comment: I need the value of the sequence that has just been inserted in my application. So, I am retrieving the value from the sequence and then inserting that value by firing another insert query. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to prematurely optimise the solution by asking what is faster. Regardless of the answer, a request between an external application (e.g. Java) and the Oracle database is likely to be orders of magnitudes slower than retrieving a sequence or a query within the database.

Reduce the number of calls from Java to the database before you look at whether some internal part of the database will save you a few micro-seconds because it takes a cached value rather than looking it up from a hard drive.

> I need the value of the sequence that has just been inserted in my application. So, I am retrieving the value from the sequence and then inserting that value by firing another insert query. Is there any other way?

Use a stored procedure to prevent multiple round trips between Java and Oracle:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_data(
  in_value1      IN  YOUR_TABLE.VALUE1%TYPE,
  in_value2      IN  YOUR_TABLE.VALUE2%TYPE,
  in_other_value IN  OTHER_TABLE.VALUE%TYPE,
  out_id         OUT YOUR_TABLE.ID%TYPE,
  out_succcess   OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO your_table ( id, value1, value2 )
  VALUES ( your_table_seq.NEXTVAL, in_value1, in_value2 )
  RETURNING id INTO out_id;

  INSERT INTO other_table( id, value )
  VALUES ( out_id, in_other_value );

  out_success := 'Ok'
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    out_id      := NULL;
    out_success := 'Already exists!'; -- Handle exceptions
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Because sequence are cached into the database buffer cache, accessing the next value is very fast.
You need to adapt your sequence cache to your workload to avoid waiting for oracle to generate new sequence numbers.
Querying a sequence is not comparable to a normal query.